# Java HashMap find best matching key

Tags: java, floating-point, hashmap

I have a Java HashMap with Float keys and String values. now given a Float which is not in the HashMap, how can i find the key which ist most similar to the given Float?

Comment: I suggest you to absolutely avoid using a `HashMap` with floats as keys.

Comment: @Jack is that because the floats aren't precise enough and two similar values may give the same hash value?

Comment: It's for the opposite, because a float value won't have the same hash value also if very similar. So you'd end up having many false negatives when looking for elements in the hash map

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like a job for one of the implementations of [`java.util.NavigableMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html).

Comment: +1 its so valuable when people answer with less used utilities of languages

Comment: Good answer, one could then use `ceilingKey(K key)` and `floorKey(K key)` to determine the two closest keys and compute which one is closer afterwards.

Comment: sounds good. i'm working with Android SDK 2.1,, but can't find that interface -.-

Comment: @zolex `NavigableMap` was new in JDK 1.6, I think the Android SDK is (mostly) compatible with JDK 1.5, so that's probably why it isn't in there.

Comment: well I just downloaded a "backport-util-concurrent.jar" it's working, too bad the result is too imprecise for my needs yet...

Answer (score 1):

To use floats as keys in a HashMap is a very bad idea!

Comment: float is not an integral value. You have to deal with not obvious calculation differences. small difference in the last bit causes a different key and therefore result

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll be better using a simple array/`ArrayList` with entries sorted by the key and perform `Collections.binarySearch()`. If the entry is not found, it returns the nearest neighbour.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way

```
 HashMap<Float, String> map = new HashMap<Float, String>();

    Float newFloat = 123F;

    Float minDif = null;
    Float findedValue = null;

    for (Float key : map.keySet()) {
        Float dif = Math.abs(key - newFloat);
        if (minDif != null) {
            if (dif < minDif) {
                minDif = dif;
                findedValue = key;
            }
        } else {
            minDif = dif;
            findedValue = key;
        }
    }
```